# Themeing the action bar in android?

Tags: android

With the action bar, is there a way to theme it so that when a tab is clicked it stays highlighted?

I've managed to change the background but I just want it to be changed only when a user is on that tab.

Thanks

Comment: Read through this article: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/04/customizing-action-bar.html

Comment: I've read that, it doesnt say anything about keeping a tab highlighted on press.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define drawable for tab and set it up is described in [this](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/04/customizing-action-bar.html) article.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/tab_unselected" android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="false" android:state_selected="false"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/tab_selected" android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="false" android:state_selected="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/tab_selected_pressed" android:state_pressed="true" android:state_selected="false"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/tab_selected_pressed" android:state_pressed="true" android:state_selected="true"/>
</selector>
```